# Set time out for df and exit if it hung

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

I am trying to set time out for df  command and kill the command if its time out,

**use**: Its for a script to check df  output but some times if df hung the script also get hung.

I tried

```
TIMEOUT=10
df -hTP & PID=$!
wait $PID $TIMEOUT
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    cat <&3
  else
    kill $PID
    echo "The df command hung"
fi
```

But I am getting error

> line 166: wait: pid 10 is not a child of this shell error: List of
>
> process IDs must follow -q.

**what I am looking**

check the df command, if not hung just display df output , if hung just kill df, and continue rest of the script part.

Please help me to fix this.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html is the command to do that

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `wait` has a timeout argument? The arguments are just a list of PIDs.

Comment: thanks, , "timeout -s KILL --preserve-status 10 sudo df -hTP" this works for me